# TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type ONLY when my metaclass is imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

I create a metaclass that manage the inheritance of `__init__` function parameters through parent class.
Let me show you what I mean :

```py
class A(metaclass= MagicMeta):
    def __init__(self, a, taunt = None):
        print(locals())
        self.a = a
        self.taunt = taunt

class B(A, metaclass=MagicMeta):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class Foo(B,metaclass=MagicMeta):
    def __init__(self,yolo, name ='empty', surname = None):

        print(yolo,a,b)
        self.name = name
        self.surname= surname

o =Foo(1,2,3,taunt='taunted')
o.taunt
>>> 'taunted'
o.b
>>> 2
```

My metaclass is working well when it's writing in the same file than my class
But when I import it ,I get this error:
`TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type when my metaclass is imported`

my metaclass:

```py
import re
from inspect import Parameter
def get_args(f):
    args = list()
    kwargs = dict()
    for param in inspect.signature(f).parameters.values():
        if (param.kind == param.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD):
            if param.default ==Parameter.empty:
                args.append(param.name)
            else:
                kwargs[param.name]= param.default 
    return args, kwargs 

def  compileKwargs(dct):
    string =""
    poke = False
    for k, o  in dct.items():
        if type(o) == str:
            string+= k+"='"+o+"', "
        else:           
            string+= k+"="+str(o)+", "

    return string

def  compileKwargs2(dct):
    string =""
    poke = False
    for k, o  in dct.items():
        if type(o) == str:
            string+= k+"='"+k+"', "
        else:           
            string+= k+"="+k+", "

    return string

def stringArgs(liste):
    return " ".join([e+"," for e in liste])

def compileArgs(liste1,liste2):
    liste1.extend([e for e in liste2 if e not in liste1])
    return liste1

def editFuncName(actual: str, replace:str):
    #print('EDITFUNCNAME')
    #print(actual)
    string = re.sub('(?<=def ).*?(?=\()',replace, actual)
    #print('string', string)
    return string

import inspect
from textwrap import dedent, indent
def processCode(code : list):
    string=""
    #print('processcode')
    for i,e  in enumerate(code):
        #print('row', e)
        #print('dedent', e)
        if i != 0:
            string+=indent(dedent(e),'\t')
        else :
            string+=dedent(e)
    return string
import types
class MagicMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        #print(bases,dct)
        setattr(cls,'_CODE_', dict())

        #GET THE __init__ code function and its arg and kwargs
        # for the class and the inherited class
        func = cls.__init__
        cls._CODE_[func.__name__]= inspect.getsourcelines(func)
        args2 =get_args(cls.__bases__[0].__init__)
        
        setattr(cls,'_ARGS_', dict())
        cls._ARGS_[func.__name__]=[get_args(func), args2]

        lines = cls._CODE_['__init__']
        string= lines[0][0]
        arg, kwarg = cls._ARGS_['__init__'][0]
        arg2, kwarg2 = cls._ARGS_['__init__'][1]

        comparg = stringArgs(compileArgs(arg, arg2))
        #------------------------------------------------------

        #PROCESS arg and kwargs to manage it as string
        dct = {**kwarg ,**kwarg2}
        #print(dct)
        newargs = comparg + compileKwargs(dct)
        string = re.sub('(?<=\().*?(?=\))',newargs, string)
        print(type(arg2))
        print(arg2)
        superarg =stringArgs([a for a in arg2 if a != 'self']) + compileKwargs2(kwarg2)
        arg =stringArgs([a for a in arg2 if a != 'self'])
        printt = "print({})\n".format(arg)
        printtt = "print(locals())\n"
        print(superarg)
        #--------------------------------------------------------

        #ADD the super().__init__ in the __init__ function
        superx = "super({},self).{}({})\n".format(cls.__name__, func.__name__, superarg)
        #superx = "super().{}({})\n".format( func.__name__, superarg)
        print(superx)
        code = lines[0]
        #print('LINE DEF', code[0])
        #--------------------------------------------------------

        #BUILD the code of the new __init__ function
        code[0]= editFuncName(string, 'tempo')
        code.insert(1, printt)
        code.insert(2, "print(self, type(self))\n")
        if len(bases)>0:
            code.insert(3, superx)
 
        print('code:',code)
        codestr  = processCode(code)
        #print('précompile', codestr)
        #--------------------------------------------------------

        #REPLACE the __init__ function code
        comp = compile(codestr, '<string>','exec')
        #print(comp)
        exec(comp)
        cls.__init__ = types.MethodType(eval('tempo'), cls)
        #print(eval('tempo.__code__'))
        #--------------------------------------------------------
```

I would avoid to set the code of my metaclass each time I need it

furthermore, I think , for deeply understanding python, it is a good opportunity to learn why import change the class error behaviour, when its inner code is modify dynamically

Comment: Why are you using a metaclass for something that a straightforward use of `super` already handles just fine? What exactly does `MagicMeta` *do*?

Comment: I give you an exemple, It handle to automatically, make inherited arg and kwargs , through `__init__` function, If one day , I update the arg of the `__init__` A class,  the  B and Foo class will be automatically updated without have to rewriting them.
You can notice that `taunt` kwarg  is not set in the Foo and B `__init__` function, but I can still set it in the Foo instance .

Comment: just try it, and add a new kwarg in the `__init__` A class function, and set it , in a new Foo instance `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

So I think that with some tweaks, you can solve this problem without using a metaclass here. It looks like you want to use inheritance to have your Foo instance contain b, a, and taunt. But you are passing them in using positional args which is problematic. One solution would be to ingest *args and **kwargs, and pass them to ancestor classes in super calls. Then we could access and remove args[0] to set b and a. That is concerning because if the inheritance order is changed, what is b and a change.
For example:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    args = list(args)
    a = args.pop(0)
    self.a = a
    try:
        super().__init__(*args)
    except TypeError:
        pass

class B:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    args = list(args)
    b = args.pop(0)
    self.b = b
    try:
        super().__init__(*args)
    except TypeError:
        pass

class C(B,A):
    pass

class D(A, B):
    pass

c = C('a', 'b')
d = D('a', 'b')
>>> c.__dict__
{'b': 'a', 'a': 'b'}
>>> d.__dict__
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```

We cannot depend upon this method to reliably set what a and b are.
So instead we should use keyword args.
This code uses keyword arguments to set those ancestor parameters:

```
class NewA:
    def __init__(self, *, a, taunt = None):
        self.a = a
        self.taunt = taunt

class NewB(NewA):
    def __init__(self, *, b, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.b = b

class NewFoo(NewB):
    def __init__(self, yolo, name ='empty', surname = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.surname= surname

f = NewFoo(1, b=2, a=3,taunt='taunted')
>>> print(f.__dict__)
{'a': 3, 'taunt': 'taunted', 'b': 2, 'name': 'empty', 'surname': None}
```

In it we use a new ability in python3 to require named arguments.
When we try to omit a, we get:

```
>>> NewFoo(1, b=2, taunt='taunted')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'a'
```

We can require these named arguments by:

- using a * as an argument which tells python that all arguments after it are named
- for those named arguments do not set a default value
  Per [the python docs on function signatures](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) `Parameters after “*” or “*identifier” are keyword-only parameters and may only be passed used keyword arguments.`

Comment: I know that we can solve this problem with kwargs and args, but it doesn't explain me, the cause of why a metaclass in the file is workin well but not  when it's imported from an other file.
It could be useful to understand it .